Is it possible to change navigation bar background color for a specific view controller in UINavigationController?
I have a UINavigationController Stack like this :
UINavigationController -> RootViewController-> OtherControllers->...

I wanna the  UINavigationBar background color

set to red color when the RootViewController is displaying
(topmost in the UINavigationController's stack) .
set to green color when the non-RootViewController is displaying
in the UINavigationController.

Is there any nice way to do this kind of work (other than set the bar tint color manually for each controller)?

Yes, there is a way to do that. Set the appearance of the view controller's navigation item.

Thanks @matt , seems the background color of navigaitonbar is not belong to UINavigationItem?

You didn't listen to what I said. The appearance does belong to the navigation item. And it has a background color. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem#3282996

do you mean UINavigationBarAppearance? I have tried modify this , but this UINavigationBarAppearance will modify the whole navigation controller entirely, if I set the UINavigationBarAppearance 's background to red , all the controllers will be red too

Ok, it's fine if you don't want to believe me.

Thanks @matt , I have tried the way you suggested .set UINavigationBarAppearance to red in RootViewController's viewDidLoad . But the navigation bar is still red when push other controllers . I wanna the  navigation bar  background color to green when pushing other controllers. Did I make something wrong?

OK , I got the problem , I set the custom UINavigationBarAppearance to navigationController.navigationBar not the navigationItem. Thanks so much @matt

Thanks @matt's answer. The UINavigationBarAppearance can do this kind of work change bar appearance for specific controller
But at first , my code is not working after doing as the official guide:

Seems this guide is some kind of misleading .
you can't set the custom appearance to the navigation controller itself . you have to set it to the navigaitonItem
and it works now:
UINavigationBarAppearance* appear = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
[appear setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

//    self.navigationController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appear;
//    self.navigationController.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appear;
//    self.navigationController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appear;
//    self.navigationController.navigationBar.compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appear;
    self.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appear;
    self.navigationItem.compactAppearance = appear;
    self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appear;


UINavigationBar.appearance() is still useful in the case before the controller was loaded. Otherwise, it can't replace the current appearance.

@sonle ,thanks for supplement . I 'll give it a try and add it to my answer

@sonle , I have write a demo about it , In fact , if you did not config UINavigationBar.appearance before , the modify of appearance for navigationItem  is still working.

Yeah, I mean it will work as a singleton.
